# unable to change the behaviour of each component in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to create list of people with whom User can connect,When the User clicks on connect button it will send a request from the User to other User but whenever I click on connect button all the list button changes to requestd status which shoudn't work like that it should only make changes in the Item which was clicked And I don,t know how am I gonna make It work

[image][image]

addPeople.html code is

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="theme">
    <ion-title>Search People <ion-icon style="position:absolute;right: 1vw;"name="search"></ion-icon></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let user of userList">
    <ion-row center text-center>
      <ion-col no-padding  center text-center>
        <ion-item class="no-padding" center text-center>
          <img (click)="showProfile(user)" class="img" src="{{user.profileImg}}" alt="Picture was not Found">
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col center text-center  style="background-color: royalblue" >
       <ion-label>{{user.name}}</ion-label>
        <button *ngIf="sentRequest"ion-button class="btn" (click)="connect(user)">Connect</button>
        <button *ngIf="requested" ion-button class="btn" (click)="cancelRequest()">Cancel Request</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

addPeople.ts code is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UserProvider } from '../../providers/user/user';
import { UtilityMethods} from  '../../helper/auxilaries/utilities/utilities.service';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-people',
  templateUrl: 'add-people.html',
})
export class AddPeoplePage {

  userList : Array<any> =[];
  requested : Boolean = false;
  sentRequest : Boolean = true;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
     public navParams: NavParams,
     public userprovider : UserProvider,
     public toastCtrl : UtilityMethods
     ) {

    this.userprovider.getUsersList().subscribe((res : any) => {
       this.userList = res;
    })
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AddPeoplePage');
  }

  showProfile(params){
    this.navCtrl.push('UserDetailsPage',{'user': params});
  }

  connect(){
    this.requested = true;
    this.sentRequest = false
    this.toastCtrl.doToast('Connection request Send');
  }
  cancelRequest(){
    this.requested = false;
    this.sentRequest = true;
     this.toastCtrl.doToast('Connection request cancelled');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make `request` and `sentRequest` attributes of the user.
The HTML should change like so

```
      <ion-col>
        <ion-label>{{user.name}}</ion-label>
        <button *ngIf="user.sentRequest"ion-button class="btn" (click)="connect(user)">Connect</button>
        <button *ngIf="user.requested" ion-button class="btn" (click)="cancelRequest(user)">Cancel Request</button>
      </ion-col>
```

and the typescript will have to change to something like

```
  connect(user) {
    user.requested = true;
    user.sentRequest = false
    this.toastCtrl.doToast('Connection request Send');
  }

  cancelRequest() {
    user.requested = false;
    user.sentRequest = true;
    this.toastCtrl.doToast('Connection request cancelled');
  }
```